# Oracle Database for Web Content Portlet in Liferay

Tags: oracle, liferay, liferay-6

We have created a web content portlet in liferay which allows users to select two fields  from a drop box (The data for this dropbox should come from oracle database) ON selecting the required fields from the database and clicking on submit. The data related to these two fields should be displayed from the same portlet. THe database to be used for this portlet is Oracle.

How should I modify so that oracle database is applied only for this web content portlet?

I want the data to come from oracle database for this web content portlet and based on this selection, the relevant information should be displayed in the same portlet.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Individual portlets can connect to anything without other portlets knowing about the resources.

Configure a DataSource in your portlet code, connect to it and select from it.